# Is there a way to access clap arguments from everywhere?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, clap

I am building a command-line application using `clap`. I have many CLI arguments and many different parts of the application behave differently based on these arguments.

It is a hassle to make them accessible in every part though, as either every function needs to take the args as a parameter (which would introduce a lot of redundancy and unwanted code) or every struct needs to hold an instance of it, which also duplicates code and needs more memory.

In a programming language like Python, I would have a global variable that would be accessible from every point in my program - however I don't think that's possible in Rust, as the following snippet fails to compile:

```rust
const ARGS: cli::Args = cli::Args::parse();
```

`error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn <...cli::Args as Parser>::parse in statics`

(cli::Args is a struct containing the arguments via clap's `derive` API).

What would be the most idiomatic way to achieve this behavior (having `args` available everywhere) in Rust?

Comment: Take a look at lazy_static! macro

Comment: @IanAsh Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. I used this crate once (for regular expressions), but didn't know it was applicable in a general case.